# How to run websockets with docker container start in laravel application

Tags: laravel, docker, websocket

I am new to Docker and WebSockets. I am using docker in my one of the laravel project. I have followed steps from the following link to setup docker[laravel+docker](https://medium.com/@ahmeeddhon/laravel-docker-using-alpine-1f80fab7359b). Also, I installed WebSockets from [this](https://docs.beyondco.de/laravel-websockets/) link. My docker is running successfully after following the steps.

Now I want WebSockets to run automatically when the docker container starts. For it, I have added following code to **supervisord-app.conf**

```
[program:websockets]
command=/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/websocket-service/artisan websockets:serve
numprocs=1
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=www-data-new
```

Following is my app.dockerfile

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine

RUN apk --update add wget \
  curl \
  git \
  grep \
  build-base \
  libmemcached-dev \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  libxml2-dev \
  imagemagick-dev \
  pcre-dev \
  libtool \
  make \
  autoconf \
  g++ \
  cyrus-sasl-dev \
  libgsasl-dev \
  supervisor

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql tokenizer xml
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net \
    && pecl install memcached \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.3 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt

RUN rm /var/cache/apk/* && \
    mkdir -p /var/www

COPY supervisord-app.conf /etc/supervisord.conf

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n", "-c", "/etc/supervisord.conf"]
```

Following is my docker-compose.yml file

```
   version: '2'

    services:
      app:
        build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}

  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 8080:80

  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=
    ports:
      - 33061:3306

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

Docker runs successfully but my WebSocket server does not start with it. Can anyone help me how to do it?

Comment: you need to find the websocket port and put it in the dokcer-compose file

Comment: websocket port is 6001 but id don't to where to put in docker-compose file

Comment: If I'm right you need to access to your websocket outside of your container?

Comment: I need it to be run when I hit ```docker-compose up``` command.

Comment: What is the reason behind using `supervisordˋ?

Comment: Actually i don't know. i am just learning so i used it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208238/discussion-between-loic-lopez-and-dhara).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate your two container like:

**app.dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7-cli-alpine

RUN apk --update add wget \
  curl \
  git \
  grep \
  build-base \
  libmemcached-dev \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  libxml2-dev \
  imagemagick-dev \
  pcre-dev \
  libtool \
  make \
  autoconf \
  g++ \
  cyrus-sasl-dev \
  libgsasl-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql tokenizer xml
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net \
    && pecl install memcached \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.3 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt

RUN rm /var/cache/apk/* && \
    mkdir -p /var/www

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/php", "/var/www/html/websocket-service/artisan", "websockets:serve"]
```

I have changed at the top of the file `php:7-fpm-alpine` because in this case you just need to run a command and not to run the php-fpm server which serve the web requests

**web.dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7-fpm-alpine

RUN apk --update add wget \
  curl \
  git \
  grep \
  build-base \
  libmemcached-dev \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  libxml2-dev \
  imagemagick-dev \
  pcre-dev \
  libtool \
  make \
  autoconf \
  g++ \
  cyrus-sasl-dev \
  libgsasl-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql tokenizer xml
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net \
    && pecl install memcached \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.3 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable memcached \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt

RUN rm /var/cache/apk/* && \
    mkdir -p /var/www
```

Here you can let the `ENTRYPOINT` directive which is setup by the base container `php:7-fpm-alpine`

**[EDIT 1]**

You can also refer to my old school project: [ExoSuite/exosuite-docker](https://github.com/ExoSuite/exosuite-docker)

and more precisely to: [docker-compose.dev.yml](https://github.com/ExoSuite/exosuite-docker/blob/master/docker-compose.dev.yml) in this docker-compose file `Laravel Horizon` is run by his container [laravel-artisan](https://github.com/ExoSuite/exosuite-docker/tree/master/laravel-artisan) so this file can help you as an example for your problem.

**[EDIT 2]**

If you want to your `6001` port to be accessed outside of your `app` container modify you app directive as follows:

```
app:
   build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "6001:6001"
    environment:
      - DB_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - DB_HOST=${DB_HOST}
```

Comment: It runs but I can't see my WebSocket started. it doesn't show 6001 running